# fetch particular event from google calendar in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-calendar-api

I want to fetch a particular event from google calendar.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)fetchEvents {
    GTLQueryCalendar *query = [GTLQueryCalendar queryForEventsListWithCalendarId:calendarId];

    query.timeMin = [GTLDateTime dateTimeWithDate:startDate
                                     timeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];;
    query.timeMax = [GTLDateTime dateTimeWithDate:endDate timeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];

    query.singleEvents = YES;
    query.orderBy = kGTLCalendarOrderByStartTime;

    [self.service executeQuery:query
                  delegate:self
          didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:)];
}

- (void)displayResultWithTicket:(GTLServiceTicket *)ticket
         finishedWithObject:(GTLCalendarEvents *)events
                      error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error == nil) {

        if (events.items.count > 0) {

        }
    }
   }
```

Now I'm able to get the events between the start date and end date. I have created one calendarEvent which is from April 3 to April 5 and its time is 3pm to 4pm and event name is Meeting...

Now I want to know whether this event is already there or not.  If it is not there I can add.

And also I want to delete the particular event if the user delete it.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Make a call to [Events.list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) as it returns all your events with the corresponding eventIds. In doing so, you can see if the events you've created are present.

You can check the [code samples for Objective-C](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios) in the guide. Here's a snippet:

```
// Construct a query and get a list of upcoming events from the user calendar. Display the
// start dates and event summaries in the UITextView.
- (void)fetchEvents {
  GTLQueryCalendar *query = [GTLQueryCalendar queryForEventsListWithCalendarId:@"primary"];
  query.maxResults = 10;
  query.timeMin = [GTLDateTime dateTimeWithDate:[NSDate date]
                                       timeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];;
  query.singleEvents = YES;
  query.orderBy = kGTLCalendarOrderByStartTime;

  [self.service executeQuery:query
                    delegate:self
           didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:)];
}
```